# Android - Registering a broadcast receiver for two intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I was wondering is it possible to register a broadcast receiver to receive two intents?

My code is as follows:

```
sipRegistrationListener = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction(); 

        if (SIPEngine.SIP_REGISTERED_INTENT.equals(action)){
            Log.d("SETTINGS ", "Got REGISTERED action");
        }   

        if (SIPEngine.SIP_UNREGISTERED_INTENT.equals(action)){
            Log.d("SETTINGS ", "Got UNREGISTERED action");
        }   
    }
};

context.registerReceiver(sipRegistrationListener, new IntentFilter(SIPEngine.SIP_REGISTERED_INTENT));
context.registerReceiver(sipRegistrationListener, new IntentFilter(SIPEngine.SIP_UNREGISTERED_INTENT));
```

I get the REGISTERED Intent everytime I send it but I never get the UNREGISTERED Intent when I send it.

Should I set up another Broadcast receiver for the UNREGISTERED Intent?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Don't create your `IntentFilter` inline, then use the [`addAction`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#addAction(java.lang.String)) method to add the `UNREGISTERED` action, i.e.:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SIPEngine.SIP_REGISTERED_INTENT);
filter.addAction(SIPEngine.SIP_UNREGISTERED_INTENT);
context.registerReceiver(sipRegistrationListener, filter);
```

Comment: Thanks for that Christopher, I have now come across another problem, I cant seem to send the intent from the onDestroy() method, the intent never gets sent. Is this a limitation of the onDestroy() method or just bad programming on my part? :)

Comment: Macarse: Yes, you just include two <action> tags in your <intent-filter>.

Donal: Is the `BroadcastReceiver` that you're registering to handle this in the same `Activity` in which you're calling `onDestroy()`? If so, your BR is likely being torn down before the broadcast `Intent` can reach it. Otherwise, I'm not aware of any restriction on when you can send broadcasts -- not that I've explicitly tried it from an `onDestroy` method...

Comment: Thanks Christopher, that was it indeed and I have sorted it out now

Comment: You were missing a `new` keyword there, I've added it for you.