# Two event for one Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

have an Android app that uses the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED. According to the docs, I should not allow installing/moving this app to external storage. Users, however, do not understand this (probably due to very little internal storage on some devices) - and demand the option to install on external storage (via low-star ratings).

So i also have a same BroadcastReceiver listening for EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE. My question is can i use both with same BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2317573/985143

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is can i use both with same BroadcastReceiver?

Sure. Have both actions in the `<intent-filter>`. In `onReceive()`, check the action of the incoming `Intent` to identify which broadcast you need to respond to.