# Android:The if statement of wifi scan result is not being entered?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have built BroadcastReceiver in my MainActivity to catch system broadcast(internet connection and wifi scan result). The internet connection broadcast is being caught but I am facing problem to catch the broadcast of the wifi scan result. no error is being thrown. I do not know what shall I add additional to get it work. I appreciate any help.

MainActivity:

```js
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 BroadcastReceiverListener receiver;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  receiver = new BroadcastReceiverListener();

 }

 private class BroadcastReceiverListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   //This if statement is being arrived
   if (intent.getAction().equals(
     android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
         //This code  works without BroadcastReceiver.

   }

   else if (intent.getAction().equals(
     android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
    // I am getting here broadcast for the internet connection

   }
  }
 };

 protected void onResume() {

  IntentFilter wifi = new IntentFilter();
  wifi.addAction(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
  registerReceiver(receiver, wifi);

  IntentFilter conn = new IntentFilter();
  conn.addAction(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
  registerReceiver(receiver, conn);

  super.onResume();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  unregisterReceiver(receiver);
  super.onDestroy();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create two IntentFilters, just create the one and use `addAction()` to add multiple actions:

```
IntentFilter wifi = new IntentFilter();
wifi.addAction(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
wifi.addAction(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
registerReceiver(receiver, wifi);
```

See here:

[Android - Registering a broadcast receiver for two intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317544/android-registering-a-broadcast-receiver-for-two-intents)